# How to pass Html.Password helper's value to the Action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a view which gets username and password and needs to pass it to the Database. I can pass the username but not the password.

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "label-control" })
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "", value = "Text" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "label-control" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditUserSubmit(string UserName, string Password, string ProcessType)
{
    string process;
    string name = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
    process = (ProcessType == "Processed") ? "P" : "B";
    DB.Entities.user users = db.users.Where(m => m.username == name).FirstOrDefault();
    users.password = Password;
    users.processtype = process;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Manager");
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the whole View

```
@model NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.MVC.Models.AdministrationModel
@{string name = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();}

<div class="x-form-wrapper">
    <div class="x-form-title">
        <h3><strong>User Detail for <b>@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]</b></strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="x-form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "label-control" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "", value = "Text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "label-control" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProcessType, new { @class = "label-control" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProcessType, new[]{
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Processed", Value = "Processed" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Both", Value = "Both" }
                }, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProcessType, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a href="/Administration/EditUserSubmit/@name" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</a>
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Manager", "Administration", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-default" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@{
    string password = "";
    var entity = new NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.DB.Entities.sstpEntities();
    var data = from db in entity.users
                where db.username == name
                select db;
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        password = item.password;
        <script>document.getElementById("Password").defaultValue = "@password"</script>
        if (item.processtype == "B")
        {
            <script>document.getElementById("ProcessType").value = "Both"</script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>document.getElementById("ProcessType").value = "Processed"</script>
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the JS code you're using for Submitting the form?

Comment: There is no JS code.

Comment: Then how are you passing values to the action? Via Form submit url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating the password textbox like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It's clear that you're using a view model class that has `UserName` and `Password` property. I'd guess that it also has `ProcessType` property. Since you have the following syntax at the top of your view

```
@model NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.MVC.Models.AdministrationModel
```

You can use `NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.MVC.Models.AdministrationModel` as the parameter of your controller action method as below

```
public ActionResult EditUserSubmit(NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.MVC.Models.AdministrationModel model)
{
    string process;
    string name = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
    process = (model.ProcessType == "Processed") ? "P" : "B";
    DB.Entities.user users = db.users.Where(m => m.username == name).FirstOrDefault();
    users.password = model.Password;
    users.processtype = process;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Manager");
}
```

The value of `model.Password` will be what you enter in the password textbox.

**EDIT**

After looking at the whole view code, this is where you're wrong

```
<a href="/Administration/EditUserSubmit/@name" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</a>
```

You can't submit the page using an anchor tag and without `<form>` tag. You need to have a `<form>` tag and a submit button inside it. The `<form>` tag can be generated using `Html.BeginForm` helper method. Change your view code to below

```
@model NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.MVC.Models.AdministrationModel
@{string name = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();}

<div class="x-form-wrapper">
    <div class="x-form-title">
        <h3><strong>User Detail for <b>@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]</b></strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="x-form-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EditUserSubmit", "Administration"))
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "label-control" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "", value = "Text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "label-control" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProcessType, new { @class = "label-control" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProcessType, new[]{
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Processed", Value = "Processed" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Both", Value = "Both" }
                }, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProcessType, null, new { @class = "alert-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Manager", "Administration", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-default" })
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
@{
    string password = "";
    var entity = new NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.DB.Entities.sstpEntities();
    var data = from db in entity.users
                where db.username == name
                select db;
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        password = item.password;
        <script>document.getElementById("Password").defaultValue = "@password"</script>
        if (item.processtype == "B")
        {
            <script>document.getElementById("ProcessType").value = "Both"</script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>document.getElementById("ProcessType").value = "Processed"</script>
        }
    }

}
```

You should also add `[HttpPost]` attribute and change your controller action method as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserSubmit(NV.Tax.SST.Gateway.MVC.Models.AdministrationModel model)
{
    string process = (model.ProcessType == "Processed") ? "P" : "B";
    DB.Entities.user users = db.users.Where(m => m.username == model.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
    users.password = model.Password;
    users.processtype = process;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Manager");
}
```

Comment: It does work as a TextBoxFor. But when I try implementing PasswordFor it does not pass the data to the action.

Comment: How do you generate the `<form>` tag? Do you use `Html.BeginForm` helper? Please show the code.